# Is this MOSFET a good choice? PWM -> FET -> DC Fan

Tags: pic, dc-motor, mosfet

I am planning on using a PIC microcontroller's IO pin (3.3V Logic) to drive this MOSFET that will drive a 12V DC fan:

[MOSFET N-CH 60V 2.7A SOT-23-3](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irLML0060pbf.pdf)

According to the datasheet, there is a diode in the equivalent circuit, is this diode used as a flyback diode, and is it suitable for a 12V DC fan (without an external flyback diode)? Also, how over/underkill am I going with this thing? I haven't used motor control in an embedded system before, so any tips are welcome.

The kind of fan I plan on powering is a [simple micro fan](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2102824).

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: The Zener diode in the MOSFET symbol is there as a reminder that it exists. The diode itself is a side effect of the transistor's construction, not an intentionally designed component. Using the diode in forward conduction or reverse breakdown generally reduces the life of the transistor. If you need a diode at that point in the circuit, use an actual discrete diode.

Comment: I'm no expert on this but a lot of computer fans are essentially brushless DC motors with on board controls. Can you PWM a brushless DC motor with that kind of built in circuitry? Aren't they designed for a steady voltage and fan speeds based off of voltage?

Comment: Remember, that with N-MOSFET you will have to cut the ground plane => will not be able to sence RPM, if you need this.

Comment: @MikeL The body diode *can* be an intentionally designed component.  The ZVS mode SMPS designs use the body diode as part of their function, and the manufacturers sell  parts for this purpose.  "The FDmesh™ associates all advantages of
reduced on-resistance and fast switching with an
intrinsic fast-recovery body diode. It is therefore
strongly recommended for bridge topologies, in
particular ZVS phase-shift converters."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not a suitable transistor for this application since you want to drive the base with 3.3V.  The 60V rating is also overkill.

A much better fit for this application is the [IRLML2502](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irlml2502.pdf).  That is specified for lower gate voltage.  It can only handle 20V, but that's well above your 12V spec.

The body diode is not in the right place to serve as a load flyback diode.  Think of the load as a inductor, and you'll see that it will try to make a *high* voltage when turned off, not a low voltage.  You still need a reverse diode accross the load (the fan in this case).  Make sure the diode is rated for at least the same current as the fan.  A regular silicon diode will be fine as long as you turn the fan only on or off, and don't try to turn it on shortly after having turned it off.  If you plan to do PWM control, then use a Schottky diode since those have essentially zero reverse recovery time for this purpose.  It will also be slightly more efficient.  At 12V it will be no problem finding a suitable Schottky diode.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are driving the MOSFET fully on and fully off, relatively quickly, then this should be fine.  One area where you can get into trouble is if you don't turn it on/off quick enough and the FET is actually dissipating a fair amount of heat.  Odds are that you won't have that problem.

I would advise against using the internal diode as a flyback diode.  In some cases it can be done, but as a general rule the internal diodes in FET's are not very good.